# Bootstrap: Reapply button styles

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button that is generated by ajax. Unfortunately, the new button doesn't have the bootstrap style.

How can I refresh the styles?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `success` function to add the appropriate classes.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ...,
    success: function () {
        $('.my-button-class').addClass('btn btn-default');
    }
});
```